# How to launch multiple web rest services with only one client

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, client, jax-rs

I am interested in developing a web application.
I need to invoke ten web services at the same time, and with a single JAX-RS client.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
launcherPS(i)
}

static void launcherPS(int id){
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        String name="LampPostZ"+id;
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI(name));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Launching of PresenceSensor "+id+" .........");
        target.path("PresenceSensor/"+id).path("change").request()
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);    
    }
    private static URI getBaseURI(String project) {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8081/"+project).build();                                                            
    }
}
```

This code allows, invoking the second service except that the first terminates its operation. But, I need to launch them at the same time.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on JEE7/JAX-RS 2.0, you can use the `async()` method:

```
target.path("PresenceSensor/"+id).path("change").request()
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .async()
                .get(/* see Javadocs for various options! */);
```

Generally this returns a `Future`. See details in JAX-RS 2.x specs, chapter 8.4.

If on the other hand you are lucky enough to be using JEE8/JAX-RS 2.1, you can make use of the new `rx()` method, which can give you a `CompletionStage` or even richer RX things:

```
target.path("PresenceSensor/"+id).path("change").request()
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .rx() // ONLY JAX-RS 2.1
                .get(/* see Javadocs for various options! */);
```

See JAX-RS 2.1 specs, chapter 5.7.

NOTE: If you want to do something with the results of the invocations, you will need to adjust the code accordingly, e.g. compose the various `CompletionStages` to be notified when all finish.